# Examples of divisible Lie algebras

Tags: gr.group-theory, lie-algebras

We say that a nonzero Lie algebra $L$ is **divisible**, if for all elements $a$ and $b$ with $a\neq 0$, there exists $x\in L$ such that $[a, x]=b$. What are examples of divisible Lie algebras?

Comment: Do you have any examples of such Lie algebras? They are clearly simple, but I can't think of an example off the top of my head.

Comment: In fact I proved there existence. Further, every Lie algebra can be embedded in a divisible Lie algebra. But I have no example.

Comment: How have you proved their existence without getting an example?

Comment: Yes! see this link https://www.academia.edu/5648770/Embeddings_Coming_From_Algebraically_Closed_Groups my proof uses AC.

Comment: @Dietrich: $sl(\infty)$ fails: the image of $ad(E_{12})$ does not contain $E_{34}$.

Comment: So no finitary simple Lie algebra is possible ?

Comment: @Dietrich: well, for a semisimple element $x$, its centralizer is nondegenerate for the Killing form, and the image of $ad(x)$ is contained in its orthogonal. In particular unless $x=0$, there is no $y$ such that $[x,y]=x$.

Comment: (NB I assume the field to be the complex numbers or at least char 0, the OP should specify.) Actually in a finite-dimensional Lie algebra $[x,y]=x$ implies $ad(x)$ nilpotent; in particular if $L$ is divisible and locally finite-dimensional then it's locally nilpotent.

Comment: The divisible Lie algebras  I proved their existence are not finitely presented, further if $ad\ x$ is nilpotent, then $x$ equals zero. I didn't checked if this is also true for semisimple elements or not.

Comment: I am sure by the axiom of choice that such Lie algebras do exist, I am interested to know is it possible to construct such a Lie algebra without AC.

Comment: @M.Shahryari: yes what you asked is clear. Still, it's probably possible, if the ground field is $\mathbf{Q}$ (please say something about the ground field in your question!) to produce some ZF-constructive process and thus prove the existence in ZF; still it might be far from a "natural example".

Comment: Clearly such an example will not be a natural one, it likes a sort of Monster. There is no restriction on field. The cardinal of the field controls the dimension of Lie algebra. For example there exists one such a Lie algebra over $\mathbb{R}$ of dimension at most $\aleph_1$. In the case of finite field such a Lie algebra is countable and every finite dimensional Lie algebras embeds in it.

Comment: @M.Shahryari: do you have a proof that there exists no divisible Lie algebra over a countably infinite field, of countably infinite dimension? what do you mean by ``clearly such an example will not be a natural one?"

Comment: @YvesCornulier: No, over countably infinite filed there exists a divisible Lie algebra of countable dimension. By "natural" I mean a Lie algebra which belongs to some well-known class.